# Parametrizing the vertices of a partial hexagon

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to parametrize the vertices partial hexagon, as illustrated as the outer hexagon in the following (rough) figure below

[image]

What I mean by this is perhaps best illustrated by first parametrizing the vertices of the inner hexagon, which are shown in blue.

In the coordinate system centered at the origin I'd write them as the points $\{x,y\} = \{s,0\}, \{s\cos{(\pi/3)},s\sin{(\pi/3)}\}, \{s\cos{(2\pi/3)},s\sin{(2\pi/3)}\},\{s\cos{(3\pi/3)},s\sin{(3\pi/3)}\},\{s\cos{(4\pi/3)},s\sin{(4\pi/3)}\},\{s\cos{(5\pi/3)},s\sin{(5\pi/3)}\}$

Now, if I wanted to simply parametrize the complete outer hexagon, I'd use the same with $s \rightarrow s+d$. However, I'd like the bottom part of the hexagon to be cut off so that it aligns with the inner hexagon. This means that while the orange vertices are simply given by the ones similar to the above, the 5th and 6th vertices are different.

So my question boils down to what the coordinates of the red points are, and more so their x-coordinate; the y-coordinate is known from the inner hexagon.
I feel like this should reduce to a rather simple geometric problem, involving pretty much only the distance d and some angle. But somehow I can't seem to figure it out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x-coordinates of the 5th and 6th vertices are $x_5=-(\frac 1 2 s + d)$ and $x_6=(\frac 1 2 s + d)$. You could also write this as $x_5=(s+d) \cos(4 \pi /3) -\frac 1 2 d$ and $x_6=(s+d) \cos(5 \pi /3) +\frac 1 2 d$.